# Попасть и загреметь по полной

Tags: грамотная-речь

Возможны ли и звучат ли гладко выражения "попасть по полной",  "загреметь по полной"?

Answer (score 1):

Все выражения по-разному хорошо подходят, в зависимости от контекста. Например «попал по полной» подходит в сценарии, где кто-то участвовал в грабеже и был пойман, но меньше подходит в ситуации стрельбы из лука (к примеру, тут лучше «попал в точку»). Все фразы можно хорошо использовать.

Не совсем уверен уверен насчёт второго выражения, в нём используется два слова «загреметь» и «полно», которые не совсем совместимы.

Comment: "Загреметь по полной" - что-то вроде "сесть в тюрьму на максимально возможный (за данное преступление) срок".

Answer (score 1):

В словаре синонимов:
[**по полной**](https://%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2:%202%20%E2%80%A2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20(18)%20%E2%80%A2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83%20(7)), *наречие*
• капитально
• на всю катушку

Слова [**попасть**](https://russian_argo.academic.ru/9492/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (сильно потратиться; быть обманутым, обобранным) и [**загреметь**](https://russian_argo.academic.ru/3889/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) (провалиться, потерпеть неудачу; быть изгнанным, уволенным откуда-либо; быть пойманным, задержанным, арестованным, застигнутым на месте преступления; угодить, попасть куда-либо; очутиться где-либо (обычно о какой-либо неприятной ситуации)) — из словаря русского арго.

Выражения ***попасть по полной*** и ***загреметь по полной***, конечно, возможны (и довольно широко употребляются), но — в определенном контексте. Они характерны для разговорной или жаргонной речи (или для описания подобных ситуаций).

*Молодая угрожающим взглядом посмотрела на уже мужа. Без слов было ясно: жених **попал по полной*** (Л. Громова); *Экс-замминистру нужно найти миллиард, чтобы не **загреметь по полной*** (из статьи).